# bash: /usr/local/bin/mongo: Permission denied in Catalina OS

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-catalina

I installed homebrew then installed mongo .. when I want to run mongo it shows

```
" bash: /usr/local/bin/mongo: Permission denied "
```

I'm using Mac on Catalina OS 10.15.4 ..

By default, MongoDB stores database information in the root folder, in data/db. But the Catalina update provides read-only access to the root.

I read about this problem a lot and I think the problem with permissions in the local folder

**" /usr/local/ "**

I tried to give it permissions with

```
" sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db "
```

but it didn't work !!

also I read a way to fix that with changing path , bcuz Catalina OS never allow to change local folder permissions

https://medium.com/better-programming/installing-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-aab1cbe0c836

I did step by step but still I can't run mongo.

please help.

Comment: Also I tried to update brew .. " brew tap mongodb/brew " -->. "   brew install mongodb-community " --> " brew services start mongodb-community " !! and still not work

Comment: You can get the mongo binaries from their official website, unzip them and place them in a folder in your home directory. Then add that folder to your PATH variable. It would be easier.

Comment: I did all of that but still not work with me .." mongod --dbpath /Users/${USER]/data/bin/" --> " sudo chown -R `id -un` /Users/{USER}/data/bin/ "   -----   when I try to run **mongo** it shows ` zsh: permission denied: mongo` ,, and shows ` sudo: mongod: command not found ` when I try to run **mongod** .. thank you

Comment: This questions belongs to https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

finally , I fixed it !!

actually I don't know where the problem exactly because I've tried alot of solutions and codes before but now it fixed after these steps

```
netstat -an | grep 27017
```

then updating and starting brew again

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

change the Path

```
mongod --dbpath /users/{USER}/data/db/
```

run mongo :)

```
Mongo
```